# "mobx Invariant failed" error in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I am using Mobx with ReactJS to create a simple expense app.
Here is my main App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import { autorun } from 'mobx';
import DevTools from 'mobx-react-devtools';

import ExpenseStore from './stores/ExpenseStore';
import AddExpenseView from './components/AddExpenseView';
import CategoryView from './components/CategoryView';

var ExpenseStoreObj = new ExpenseStore();

@observer
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.updateExpense = this.updateExpense.bind(this);
    this.deleteExpense = this.deleteExpense.bind(this);
    this.categorizeExpenses = this.categorizeExpenses.bind(this);
  }

  updateExpense(newExpense) {
    ExpenseStoreObj.addExpense(newExpense);
  }

  deleteExpense(ExpenseId) {
    ExpenseStoreObj.removeExpense(ExpenseId);
  }

  categorizeExpenses() {
    return ExpenseStoreObj.categorizeExpenses();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DevTools />
        <div className="app-container">
          <div className="col-xs-6 border">
            <AddExpenseView
              allExpenses={ExpenseStoreObj.expenses}
              expenseCategories={ExpenseStoreObj.expenseCategories}
              updateExpense={this.updateExpense}
              deleteExpense={this.deleteExpense}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col-xs-6 border">
            <CategoryView
              categorizeExpenses={this.categorizeExpenses}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And this is ExpenseStore.js:

```
import { observable, computed, reaction } from 'mobx';

export default class ExpenseStore {
    constructor(props) {
        this.id = 1;
    }
    @observable expenses = [];
    expenseCategories = ['Food', 'Clothing', 'Transport'];

    handleError(message) {
        alert(message);
    }

    addExpense(newExpense) {
        if (newExpense.expenseName == '') {
            this.handleError('Please enter expense name');
        }
        else if (newExpense.expenseCategory == '') {
            this.handleError('Please select expense categorry');
        }
        else if (newExpense.expensePrice == '') {
            this.handleError('Please enter expense value');
        }
        else {
            newExpense.id = this.id++;
            this.expenses.push(newExpense);
            this.categorizeExpenses();
        }
    }

    removeExpense(expenseId) {
        let expenseIndex = this.expenses.findIndex(x => x.id == expenseId);
        this.expenses.splice(expenseIndex, 1);
    }

    categorizeExpenses() {
        let groupedResult = this.expenses.reduce(function (hash) {
            return function (r, a) {
                if (!hash[a.expenseCategory]) {
                    hash[a.expenseCategory] = { expenseCategory: a.expenseCategory, expensePrice: 0 };
                    r.push(hash[a.expenseCategory]);
                }
                hash[a.expenseCategory].expensePrice = parseInt(hash[a.expenseCategory].expensePrice) + parseInt(a.expensePrice);
                return r;
            };
        }(Object.create(null)), []);
        return groupedResult;
    }

}
```

I am getting this error in console when I add an a new expense (i.e. when `addExpense` in ExpenseStore is called): "[mobx] Invariant failed: Side effects like changing state are not allowed at this point. Are you trying to modify state from, for example, the render function of a React component? Tried to modify: ExpenseStore@2.expenses".
If I remove `this.expenses.push(newExpense)` from `addExpense`, the error vanishes

Can anyone suggest what is the issue here and how can I resolve this?

Comment: How is called `updateExpense ` in `AddExpenseView`? If it is called in the render function, it is a normal error. You must not modify the state (add an item to `@observable expenses = [];`) during a render.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setState automatically calling another method in React](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43465773/setstate-automatically-calling-another-method-in-react)